# ICS email app, SSL certificates crash bug

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, email, asus-eee-pad-transformer, certificates

Does anyone have a solution for the following situation:

Added Exchange account, tick "Accept all SSL certificates", upon saving the setting the app crashes.

Stock ICS, please see log here: https://plus.google.com/105301306662715512529/posts/exayyi7C7o8

Comment: Need some more information. Which version of OS are you running on your pad (stock ICS or custom ROM)?  Can you get a log (either via adb or aLogCat app from Play Store) of what happens around the crash?

Comment: stock ICS - eee transformer pad t300.

Comment: Log can be seen here: https://plus.google.com/105301306662715512529/posts/exayyi7C7o8

Comment: @NikitaGorshkov: Please add that information to your question.